# Having Trouble using Dash and managing windows

Tags: unity, launcher

I recently switched to the Dell XPS 13 DE from a Mac.  I'm trying to replicated the super + spacebar motions to open up a dialog to run applications on the computer but I can't seem to get it going.  Also, is there a quick guide on the best way to use key combos to snap windows?